# How to configure Cloudflare app in Grafana from code?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, grafana, cloudflare, kubernetes-helm

I'm using Grafana based on the helm chart, at the moment I have all the configurations as code, the main configuration is placed into the `vales.yaml` as part of the `grafana.ini` values, the dashboards and datasources are placed into configmaps per each datasource or dashboard and the sidecar container is in charge of taking them based on the labels.

Now I want to use apps and the first app I'm trying is the Cloudflare app from [here](https://grafana.com/grafana/plugins/cloudflare-app), the app is installed correctly using the plugins section in the chart `values.yaml` but I  don't see any documentation of how to pass the email and token of CloudFlare API by configMap or json.

Is it possible? or do I have to configure it manually inside the app settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Grafana plugins](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/plugins/developing/auth-for-datasources/#api-key-http-header-authentication) are provisionable [datasources](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/provisioning/#example-datasource-config-file).

The [CloudFlare App plugin](https://github.com/cloudflare/cloudflare-grafana-app/blob/v0.1.4/dist/plugin.json) uses `"{{.SecureJsonData.token}}"` for `X-Auth-Key` and `"{{.JsonData.email}}"}` for `X-Auth-Email`.

You could provision the Cloudflare app plugin datasource with `jsonData` and `secureJsonData`  you like to use.

The datasource `name` is the `id` given in Cloudflare app plugin `plugin.yaml` file.

You may configure `jsonData` and `secureJsonData` for this datasource in `datasources` field in `values.yaml`.

For example,

```
datasources: 
  datasources.yaml:
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: cloudflare-app
      jsonData:
        email: bilbo@shi.re
      secureJsonData:
        token: extra-tolkien
```

Answer (score 2):

To update this answer, this plugin began support of API tokens in December 2020. In order to have the Grafana provisioner pick up your token, if you're using an API token instead of the email/API key, you must specify:

```
    jsonData:
      bearerSet: true
    secureJsonData:
      bearer: "your-api-token"
```